# Grunt error when running Sails.js app in Amazon ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, sails.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am moving a Sails.js app hosted on Heroku to Amazon ElasticBeanstalk. When the application launches, it throws the following Grunt error (pulled from `eb logs`):

```
info:    Sails              <|    .-..-.
info:    v0.11.5             |\
info:                       /|.\
info:                      / || \
info:                    ,'  |'  \
info:                 .-'.-==|/_--'
info:                 `--'-------'
info:    __---___--___---___--___---___--___
info:  ____---___--___---___--___---___--___-__
info:
info: Server lifted in `/var/app/current`
info: To see your app, visit http://localhost:8081
info: To shut down Sails, press <CTRL> + C at any time.

debug: --------------------------------------------------------
debug: :: Mon Feb 29 2016 08:21:46 GMT+0000 (UTC)

debug: Environment : development
debug: Port        : 8081
debug: --------------------------------------------------------
error: ** Grunt :: An error occurred. **
error:
------------------------------------------------------------------------
>> FileError: '../bower_components/bootstrap/less/grid.less' wasn't found in assets/styles/importer.less on line 9, column 1:
>> 8 // Import Bootstrap
>> 9 @import "../bower_components/bootstrap/less/grid.less";
>> 10 @import "../bower_components/bootstrap/less/mixins.less";
Warning: Error compiling assets/styles/importer.less

Aborted due to warnings.
Running "less:dev" (less) task
------------------------------------------------------------------------

error: Looks like a Grunt error occurred--
error: Please fix it, then **restart Sails** to continue running tasks (e.g. watching for changes in assets)
error: Or if you're stuck, check out the troubleshooting tips below.

error: Troubleshooting tips:
error:
error:  *-> Are "grunt" and related grunt task modules installed locally?  Run `npm install` if you're not sure.
error:
error:  *-> You might have a malformed LESS, SASS, CoffeeScript file, etc.
error:
error:  *-> Or maybe you don't have permissions to access the `.tmp` directory?
error:      e.g., `/var/app/current/.tmp` ?
error:
error:      If you think this might be the case, try running:
error:      sudo chown -R 497 /var/app/current/.tmp
```

The same code runs fine on my local development laptop and on Heroku but not on ElasticBeanstalk. Why is it unable to find the bootstrap files? This being a PaaS, I can't even run the recommended `sudo chown` command that the log recommended. Also to be clear, I have the following command in my package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bower install; grunt build",
    "debug": "node debug app.js",
    "start": "node app.js"
}
```

I have instructed the script to run `bower install` after the NPM packages are installed in the machine. None of the images in my /assets folder seem to load either. Not sure what's going on. Please help.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? if not I may start a bounty for you. Thanks